# Compiling external C++ library (Octave) for iPhone (Fortran compiler missing?)

Tags: iphone, cross-compiling, octave

A friend of mine asked me if it would be possible to port the [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) project to the iPhone. I haven't compiled an external package for an iPhone project before, so I downloaded the source code, and then used some scripts found on a couple of different Web sites ([one](http://pseudogreen.org/blog/build%5Fautoconfed%5Flibs%5Ffor%5Fiphone.html), [two](http://latenitesoft.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-programming-tips-building-unix.html)) to try and build the libraries. However, when I try either of these scripts (which are nearly identical), they eventually die during the `configure` phase with the following error output:

```
[...snip checks...]
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking how to get verbose linking output from ... configure: WARNING: compilation failed

checking for Fortran 77 libraries of ... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory

checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... configure: error: cannot compile a simple Fortran program
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Is the problem that the iPhone SDK/Xcode doesn't include a Fortran cross-compiler, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone SDK does not include a FORTRAN compiler. Apple's last FORTRAN product was for the Apple ][, although 3rd party and/or open source compilers have existed for most systems Apple has built.

You could configure and build [gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), but it's going to be a PITA. You'll likely need to merge in changes from Apple's customized GCC 4.2 fork found under iPhone [here](http://opensource.apple.com/) with a recipe for building it for Darwin, such as [this](http://g95.darwinports.com/).

You might try [f2c](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) as the Octave project suggests.

Comment: Have you done this yourself? Just wondering if there are any specific steps/instructions/traps I should be aware of concerning f2c. I'll be giving it a try tomorrow morning.

Comment: I know FORTRAN users exist, but for me, it's just another level in the "Tron" arcade game.